# Trustworthy BitTorrent clients for Mac OS without adware/malware

Tags: osx, bittorrent

I tried downloading uTorrent and the official BitTorrent client, but the installers look like they require me to install a bunch of malware/adware/toolbars.  The uTorrent installer even hijacked my browsers and changed my search engine to Yahoo, and tried installing toolbars and plugins before I stopped it.  I'm afraid to find out what else it changed. I also downloaded the official BitTorrent client for Mac but when I launched it, it wanted to install a bunch of crapware too. If I decline to install the extra crap, the installer promptly quits.

Is there any trustworthy BitTorrent client for Mac which doesn't require you to install a bunch of crapware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transmission is a great BitTorrent client that I use on Mac OS X, as well as Linux. You can download it [here](http://www.transmissionbt.com/download/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JSTorrent](http://jstorrent.com/) [webapp for chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jstorrent/anhdpjpojoipgpmfanmedjghaligalgb?hl=en). It is reliable and very fast. I am using it from a long time. The performance is very good. No crap is added to your browser's search functionalities or anything.

It is open source. It is available in Chrome Store but you have to purchase it if you want to add it from Chrome Store.

Alternatively, it is also available from the [developer's github page](https://github.com/kzahel/jstorrent) from where he offers it for free. You have to side load the extension by enabling developer mode in extensions page of chrome.

You can any time remove the extension with a single click. No more fuss to your system.